# rails 3 Select on model with where clauses doesn't look to works

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mysqli

I have a search engine controller to have advanced search. here is my controller.

```
@search = Building.joins('INNER JOIN "floors" ON "floors"."building_id" = "buildings"."id" INNER JOIN "spaces" ON "spaces".floor_id = "floors".id')
@building = []
@building << @search.where("buildings.name like ?", params[:building_name]) if params[:building_name]
@building << @search.where("Spaces.space_type_id = ?", params[:space_type][:space_type_id]) if params[:space_type][:space_type_id]
@building.flatten!
```

But, in my WEBrick shell, i see he only do the last where. I have data in params building_name and space_type.

I take this example for another stackoverflow (i don't remember the link). But if i remove the second where, the building_name is taken.

what's wrong? bad definition of my @building array?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that you're storing two `ActiveRecord::Relation`'s, but rails isn't actually getting the results.  As a result, your flatten isn't working as you expect.

**QUESTION** Are you trying to get all buildings where name is like building_name OR a `space_type` or is it `building_name` AND `space_type`.  The solution below assumes the latter, please let me know if it's the former.

Could you try this:

```
@search = Building.joins('INNER JOIN "floors" ON "floors"."building_id" = "buildings"."id" INNER JOIN "spaces" ON "spaces".floor_id = "floors".id')
@search = @search.where("buildings.name like ?", params[:building_name]) if params[:building_name]
@search = @search.where("Spaces.space_type_id = ?", params[:space_type][:space_type_id]) if params[:space_type][:space_type_id]
@building = @search
```

This should scope your query according to each criteria but only return the values when you need them.

Comment: Yes, i would like the query building AND space_type if both have data. If only space_type have data search only space_type, same thing for building_name. I have another issue.. why i'm unable to set my like '%?%' ? i get query error if i do that. I will try your change, thanks for your help.

Comment: Kristian, after some tests, your query add AND options, but i don't know why, if params[:building_name] are empty, he add the builings.name. I tried if !params[:building_name].nil? and same problem, he add building_name. Have you an idea?

Comment: You'll want to do `@search.where("buildings.name like ?", "%#{params[:building_name]}%")` since rails will put the 's in for you.  You could also look at `MetaWhere` http://erniemiller.org/projects/metawhere/

Comment: Could it be that `params[:building_name] == ""`?  Your logic will only check for nil but if you submit a form with empty value, it will be "".  Do `unless params[:building_name].blank?` or `if !params[:building_name].blank?`

Comment: I believe that Squeel is succeeding MetaWhere, both by the same author. Try it instead http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried any other search method, sphinx, metasearch, solr, searchlogic, etc. and nothing works.. thats why i put myself a query. thanks for your help about '%${}%' works good now. thanks!

Comment: Hey, can i ask you a little more question? I would like to know how i can have more than my building.* in the select? i woule like to get data from floors and space, i've tried select('Building.name, floors.number' but in my views i got error like no more name exists. thanks

Comment: Ask a separate question (on stackoverflow) and I'll try to help you out.  Just to keep things clean.

Comment: Thanks Kristian, the new topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392846/rails-3-sql-query-select-with-joins thanks for your help