# Rails 3 SQL query select with joins

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with select fonction and joins.

here is my current query.

```
@search = Building.joins('INNER JOIN "floors" ON "floors"."building_id" = "buildings"."id" INNER JOIN "spaces" ON "spaces".floor_id = "floors".id')
```

but i want to have more option in my select to use floors.number, space.number i tried this

```
@search = Building.select('buildings.name, floors.number, spaces.number).joins('INNER JOIN "floors" ON "floors"."building_id" = "buildings"."id" INNER JOIN "spaces" ON "spaces".floor_id = "floors".id')
```

in my view i got erreor.. here is my view

```
<% for b in @building do %>

<div style='width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:5px;'>

    <div style="float:left;width:50%"><%= b.name %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'view', building_path(b) %></div>

</div>

<% end %>
```

this is the error i get

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Search_engine#show

Showing /Users/stephanebaribeau/Sites/cadifice/app/views/search_engine/show.html.erb where line #21 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"buildings", :id=>#<Building name: "gigi">}

Extracted source (around line #21):

18:     <div style='width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:5px;'>
19:     
20:         <div style="float:left;width:50%"><%= b.name %></div>
21:         <div><%= link_to 'view', building_path(b) %></div>
22:         
23:     </div>
24:
```

thanks

After adding building.id, floors.id and spaces.id on my select i try to show the floors.number and spaces.number

```
<%= debug @building %>
```

give me

```
[#<Building id: 9, name: "234234">]
```

i dont know why i have only 2 elements, maybe it's because the select are on a Building.select?

thanks

-- Update 14/09

Here is my new controller

```
  @search = Building.select('buildings.id, buildings.slug, floors.id, spaces.id, buildings.name, floors.number, spaces.number').joins('INNER JOIN floors ON floors.building_id = buildings.id INNER JOIN spaces ON spaces.floor_id = floors.id')
  @search = @search.where("buildings.name like '%#{params[:building_name]}%'") if !params[:building_name].blank?
  #@search = @search.where("buildings.name like ?", params[:building_name]) if !params[:building_name].blank?
  if params[:space_type].present?
    @search = @search.where("spaces.space_type_id = ?", params[:space_type][:space_type_id]) if !params[:space_type][:space_type_id].blank?
  end
  @search = @search.where("floors.min_net_rent >= #{params[:floor_min_rent]}") if !params[:floor_min_rent].blank?
  @search = @search.where("floors.max_net_rent <= #{params[:floor_max_rent]}") if !params[:floor_max_rent].blank?

  @building = @search
```

The problem i have now is what debug give me. only 2 fields from the building. Is it because of the Building.select? How can i get all inside my selectfield?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us the relevant models please?

Answer (score 2):

Look at your code:

```
Building.select('buildings.name, floors.number, spaces.number)...
```

You don't select the building `id`, so Rails is a bit lost when comes the time to retrieve it.

Comment: yes, ok, hehe a bad missing of my part, but how to show the content? i tried b.number (nothing show) and b.floors.number where i get an undefinied method error. thanks

Comment: you should simply add `buildings.id` to your list. No need to change your view code: The id is mandatory

Comment: Yes i know, but how to use the floors.number or spaces.number? i have added the id and all works. But i want to show the floors.number and spaces.number. Thanks

Comment: above all provide the result of `<%= debug @search %>`

Comment: I have no error message, there is no floors.number, got only white space. Does i'm right with my b.number? or i need something else?

Comment: thanks for the debug method, never tried it. But like you can see i have only 2 elements insde. trange..

Comment: did you simply try `b.floors.number`? if it doesn't work, what are your model associations?

Comment: yes i tried with b.floors.number and get error message undefinied method floors. My model associations are : buildings has many floors, and floors has_many spaces, floors are belongs_to buildings and spaces are belong_to floors.

Comment: `b.number` should be correct unless it conflicts with a method name on your model.  You can always alias it like so `b = Building.select('buildings.id, floors.number as floor_number')...` and then do `b.floor_number`

Comment: I take back my last comment.  Since a building has many floors you need to do some sort of aggregation to get the correct floor number(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this...
Hope its useful

```
@search = Building.select("buildings.name, floors.number, spaces.number").joins("INNER JOIN floors ON floors.building_id = buildings.id INNER JOIN spaces ON spaces.floor_id = floors.id")
```

Comment: Could you expand this to explain how it answers the original question?