# How to use left join in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rake file and this is the code

```rb
task :terminate_conference_channel, [ :circle ] => :environment do |t, args|
    abort "no circle" unless args[:circle]
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      begin
        circlenum = args[:circle]
        circle = Circle.find_by circle_number: circlenum
        if circle.present?
            if circle[:conference2_total_channels].present?
                conf = Confbridge.find(:first, :conditions => ["confbridges.cid = ?",circle.circle_number],

            end

        end
      rescue Exception => e
        ActiveRecord::Rollback
        logger.info "Error Terminating"
      end
    end
end
```

how can i get select statement using join

how can i convert this stament into rails?

```sql
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.confno,
    c.max_member,
    (c.max_member - 5) AS additional,
    (c.max_member - IFNULL(p.active,0)) AS vacant
FROM
    confbridges c
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        confbridge_id,
        COUNT(uid) AS active
    FROM
        confbridge_participants
    WHERE
        active = 1
    GROUP BY
        confbridge_id) AS p
    ON c.id = p.confbridge_id
WHERE
    cid = '0090000092'
ORDER BY
    vacant DESC
```

```rb
conf = Confbridge.find(:first, :conditions => ["confbridges.cid = ?",circle.circle_number],
```

this is my model

```rb
class Confbridge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :confbridge_schedules, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :confno, uniqueness: true, :allow_nil => true, :allow_blank => true

end
```

thanks :)

Comment: put your model structure here.

Comment: hello @VishalJAIN. I added my model

Comment: @kingkangkungkangking, model structure is not model class. Structure is information about tables, their fields (names, types, indices) and relations

Comment: May be [Rails 3 SQL query select with joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392846/rails-3-sql-query-select-with-joins/12899497#12899497) will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a Left join in a rails find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722106/how-do-i-do-a-left-join-in-a-rails-find)